# SQL query to count numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column like below

```
Video_id
   1
   1
   1
   2
   2
   4
   4
   4
   4
```

I am looking for a query which can extract the count as below in SQL

```
Video_id    count
   1          3
   2          2  
   4          4
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This is a simple query with count and group by please see docs first

Comment: have you search anything for this.

Comment: read the SQL docs with 'group by' tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Video_id,COUNT(Video_id)
FROM tbl 
Group By Video_id
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1634b/1)**

**O/P**

```
VIDEO_ID COUNT(VIDEO_ID)
1        3
2        2
4        4
```

Take a look at these document

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple query with `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT Video_id,COUNT(Video_id) as count
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Video_id
```

`COUNT` is an aggregate function for counting the occurence of a value in a column.
Read more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
select Video_id, count(*) as cnt from table_name group by Video_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Given below is query with sample data:

```
with my_table as 
(select 1 videoid from dual
union
select 1 videoid from dual
union
select 1 videoid from dual
union
select 2 videoid from dual
union
select 2 videoid from dual
union
select 4 videoid from dual
union
select 4 videoid from dual
union
select 4 videoid from dual
union
select 4 videoid from dual
)
select videoid,count(1) from my_table
group by videoid;
```

Assume your table name is "**VIDEO_TABLE**", then your query will be

```
SELECT VIDEO_ID, COUNT(1) FROM VIDEO_TABLE
GROUP BY VIDEO_ID
ORDER BY VIDEO_ID;
```